# external library not recognised with vue 3 + typescript + yarn

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue with vue 3 and typescript  in our project, but somehow types are not matching or not recognized:

my `main.ts`:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import LottieAnimation from "lottie-web-vue";
import Quasar from "quasar";
import quasarUserOptions from './setup/quasar-user-options'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(LottieAnimation);
app.use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions);

app.mount('#app')
```

The error on compilation:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                         4:34:00 PM

This dependency was not found:

* lottie-web-vue in ./src/main.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save lottie-web-vue
```

So far so weired, now here comes the `package.json` of the actual module:

```json
{
  "name": "lottie-web-vue",
  "version": "2.0.6",
  "description": "Airbnb Lottie-web component for Vue.js projects",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "types": "./dist/LottieAnimation.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050",
    "typecheck": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "vuejs",
    "lottie",
    "lottie-web-vue",
    "lottie-web-vuejs",
    "lottie-web-animation",
    "vue-lottie",
    "lottie-vue",
    "lottie-web",
    "web-lottie",
    "lottie-player",
    "player-lottie",
    "vue-lottie-player",
    "lottie-player-vue",
    "player-lottie-vue",
    "vue-component",
    "vue-animation",
    "lottiefiles"
  ],
  "author": "Andy Garbett",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "lottie-web": "^5.8.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^10.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.2",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vite": "^2.7.13",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.31.1"
  }
}
```

And here the linked `LottieAnimation.d.ts` file:

```js
import type { App } from "vue";
import { LottieAnimation } from "./components";
declare const _default: {
    install: (app: App) => void;
};
export default _default;
export { LottieAnimation };
//# sourceMappingURL=LottieAnimation.d.ts.map
```

Is there a way I can fix this without touching the library? If the library needs to be changed, what would be required?

You can use also have a look at https://github.com/Andreas-Schoenefeldt/lottie-web-vue-yarn-ts of you want to reproduce the thing locally.

Also here is the extensive back and forth on the lottie-web-vue ticket: https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue/issues/11

Many thx community!

Comment: The error claims you haven't installed the package. Make sure there's a `lottie-web-view` entry in your `package.json`, pointing to `^2`. If there is, run `yarn install`. Look closely for any errors. Another thing you should check is whether or not you have a folder `/node_modules/lottie-web-view`. If you made any mods to that folder, uninstall the package and reinstall it. (`yarn remove lottie-web-view && yarn add lottie-web-view`)

Comment: Hi @tao, jea I checked this first and the actual files are there in the right version.

Comment: we went for the `<video>` tag and mp4 instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved in the [new v2.0.7 release](https://github.com/garbit/lottie-web-vue/releases/tag/v2.0.7). My apologies for such a delay in updating the package.

Comment: Many thx! the project is already closed on our end, but I'll accept the answer.